# Verify Text with BR tags and text not always in the same order

Tags: text, xpath, selenium-ide, verify

My dilemma:-

I have 4 stored registrations from a results list ${VEH_REG_1}, ${VEH_REG_2}, ${VEH_REG_3} & ${VEH_REG_4}.

I am adding these registrations to a list via a UI. So you select the four vehicles and click a button, a popup then appears letting you know if you are successful or not in adding the vehicles to the list. The popup lists the registrations in a "P" tag with "BR" tag between the registrations, so each registration is on a new line.

My problem is, the stored registrations I have are not always displayed in the logical order I saved them, so verifying the text is not as straight forward as it would normally be.

I have tried verifytext with direct xpaths. I have tried verifytextpresent (but as the results list is still present, it finds the registrations even if they are not in my list) and I have tried to use the gotoif command, but I still have the same problem when it comes to the "BR" tags.

```
<div class="mbtn">
<div style="height: 120px; overflow: auto">
<span id="ctl00_phmcp_phmc_lblOfflineMarketingResult">
The selected not-pending cars have been added to the offline marketing list.
<br>
The following vehicles are not in the appropriate status:
<p>
LJ57OOB
<br>
RF56RZC
<br>
LJ58PJY
</p>
<p>
</span>
</div>
```

As I do not have 10 reputation to display images yet (Grrr!!!!) I can email you the image if it helps to understand what I am trying to achieve.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

verify them one at a time with globs so you don't need to verify the order.

```
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>//span[@id="ctl00_phmcp_phmc_lblOfflineMarketingResult"]</td>
    <td>*LJ57OOB*</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>//span[@id="ctl00_phmcp_phmc_lblOfflineMarketingResult"]</td>
    <td>*LJ58PJY*</td>
</tr>
```